# swiftで二重列挙体みたいなものを作りたい

Tags: swift

```
enum Food:Int{
    case Fruit
    case Fish
}
```

このように、一つの列挙体は作成できるのですが、FruitやFishも列挙体にしたい場合はどうすればよいのでしょうか。

使う時のイメージ

```
let apple:String  = Food.Fruit.Apple
let orange:String = Food.Fruit.Orange
let saba:String   = Food.Fish.Saba

print(apple.rawValue)  //->りんご 
print(orange.rawValue) //->おれんじ
print(saba.rawValue)   //->鯖
```

このように、Foodまでは同じですが、FruitやFishで違い、さらにFruitの中でAppleやOrangeがあるイメージです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

これでできるようです。

```
enum Food {
    enum Fish {
        case Saba
    }
}
```

ただし、ネームスペーストして使っているだけなので、Foodでマッチはできないです。結局はstruct版と変わりないと思います。

---

以下正確ではありませんでした。

多重のenumは作成できないのではないでしょうか。
以下のようにstructの中にenumを作るのは思いつきますが。

```
struct Food {
    enum Fish {
        case Saba
    }

    enum Fruit {
        case Apple
        case Orange
    }
}

Food.Fish.Saba
Food.Fruit.Apple
Food.Fruit.Orange
```

Answer (score 5):

以下コードで一応動きました。

```
enum Food {
    enum Fruit: String {
        case Orange = "みかん"
        case Apple = "りんご"
    }
    enum Fish: String {
        case Saba = "鯖"
    }
}

let apple  = Food.Fruit.Apple
let orange = Food.Fruit.Orange
let saba   = Food.Fish.Saba

print(apple.rawValue)
print(orange.rawValue)
print(saba.rawValue)
```

「ネストした型」や、「ネストされた型」をキーワードに入れると調べられると思います。